# How to use the Email template in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.5, email-templates

I develop my store in magento community edition 1.5.0.1. I need a Email template that content will be editable by admin. I create a email template through admin "Transactional Emails". Now I need to access and use that email from my custom module. How do I get it?, you have any idea let me know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it.

```
public function sendTransactionalEmail() {

        // Transactional Email Template's ID
        $templateId = 1;

        // Set sender information
        $senderName = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/name');
        $senderEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_support/email');
        $sender = array('name' => $senderName,
                    'email' => $senderEmail);

        // Set recepient information
        $recepientEmail = 'john@example.com';
        $recepientName = 'John Doe';        

        // Get Store ID
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

        // Set variables that can be used in email template
        $vars = array('customerName' => 'customer@example.com',
                  'customerEmail' => 'Mr. Nil Cust');

        $translate  = Mage::getSingleton('core/translate');

        // Send Transactional Email
        Mage::getModel('core/email_template')
            ->sendTransactional($templateId, $sender, $recepientEmail, $recepientName, $vars, $storeId);

        $translate->setTranslateInline(true);
}
```